# Find data after clicking on previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, ajax

I would like to find the data I have, after doing a search via a form.
I retrieve the id of a user, with whom I will be able to access his information.

I have a function that is used to search for individuals in a list that works.

This function is as follows and is in my service:

```
var searchUser = function(form){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    for (var key in form) {
        console.log(key, form[key]);
        formdata.append(key, form[key]);
    }
        return $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : url + '/user/search',
                data    : formdata,
                transformRequest: angular.indentity,
           }).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
         });
};
```

I then have another function in my service to retrieve the chosen user, and will show me his information:

```
var userinfo = function(idUser){
    return $http({
           method  : 'GET',
           url     : url + '/user/' + idUser,
       }).then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

For now I recover "idUser" thanks to my controller using this kind of function:

```
var addObject = function(newObj) {
element.push(newObj);
};
var getObject = function(){
return element;
};
```

Which works perfectly.

But the concern is that on this page where I have my information, I can access another page by clicking on a link.
So, by doing "previous" I lose the data about the user's info ... the application does not find the "idUser" parameter that I had previously ..
I tried several things in the day but nothing worked ..

```html
<form ng-controller="listCtrl" id="app-form5" class="list" ng-submit="search()">
  <label class="item item-input" id="app-search1" style="">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input placeholder="Search" type="search" ng-model="form.fname">
  </label>
  <a class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="search()">Search</a>
  <ion-list id="menu-list1">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="user in list track by $index" ng-click="showInfo(user.id)">{{ user.name }}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

And my controller :

```
.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, appService) {
  $scope.search = function () {
   appService.searchUser($scope.form).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    $scope.list = response;
  });
};
$scope.showInfo = function(currObj){
   appService.addObject(currObj);
   console.log(currObj);
   $state.go('infoUser');
 }
})

.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, appService) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
    viewData.enableBack = true;
  }); 
    $scope.info = appService.getObject();
    console.log($scope.info);
    appService.userinfo($scope.info).then(function(response){   
    $scope.userinfo = response; 
    console.log($scope.userinfo);           
  }); 
})
```

If someone could point me to the thing I'm looking to do it would be great :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use "cache: true" in your "infoUser" template to keep the information after pressing the previous button.
- And you're going to add the "reload ()" method so that the cache is cleared on a new search.

I will explain why:
When you do a search and choose a user, you will receive the user's information. This information will be cached so that you can find them after you go to the next page and make "back".
Then in your controller you do this:

```
$scope.showInfo = function(currObj){
  appService.addObject(currObj);
  console.log(currObj);
  $state.reload('infoUser');
  $state.go('infoUser');
}
```

Which will allow you to empty your cache after a new search, or even after choosing another user.

It should work ;)